# How to put data attributes in TR tags using ASP.net GridView?

Tags: javascript, gridview, custom-data-attribute

I have an ASP.net page with a GridView.

The GridView has a number of rows, each with an associated ID number.  I would like to make ASP.net output something like `<tr data-rowId='123'>...</tr>` for each row.  I know that I can make it output `<tr class='123'>` using the `cssClass` attribute on the `GridRow` object, but is it possible to use custom data attributes on an ASP.net GridView?

Comment: Can you put `data-rowID` as one of the fields in your Gridview, and make it hidden?

Comment: This looks like it might be what you are looking for, but the code in the answer appears to be incomplete: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1063602/give-the-id-as-a-custom-attribute-to-checkbox-in-a-grid-for-manual-update

Comment: See also http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet/grid/grid-column-custom-attributes.aspx

Comment: A previous developer did something like what Robert describes.  She would then use `$.parent` to get the row, but this seems like a kludge.

Comment: A lot of what goes on in ASP.NET seems like a kludge to me.

Comment: The more I learn about Web Development, the less I rely on the ASP.net controls to do stuff for me.

Comment: For greenfield projects I use ASP.NET MVC, but that's not always possible on existing projects.